# PHP Array to string error in printing

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an associative array I built from a mySQL table as follow:

```
<?php
$para = array();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost:8889","root","root","Contact");
$query = "SELECT List FROM `PARAMtbl`";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $para[] = $row;
}
var_dump($para);
print $paraLgth = count($para);
?>
```

I want to use the value from 'List' in a loop and I am having some trouble doing that.

## What I have tried

I tried to use:

```
foreach($para as $key => $value) { echo $value; }
for($x=0; $x < $paraLgth; $x++) { echo $para[$x]; }
```

I consistently get the error "Array to string conversion".

I checked the Array using var_dump and this is what comes out:

```
array(140) { [0]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(2) "W1" } [1]=> array(1) {
 ["List"]=> string(2) "W2" } [2]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(2) "W3" } [3]=>
 array(1) { ["List"]=> string(2) "W4" } [4]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(2) "W5"
 } [5]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(2) "W6" } [6]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> 
string(2) "W7" } [7]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(2) "W8" } [8]=> array(1) { 
["List"]=> string(2) "W9" } [9]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(3) "W10" } [10]=>
 array(1) { ["List"]=> string(3) "W11" } [11]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(3) 
"W12" } [12]=> array(1) { ["List"]=> string(3) "W13" } [13]=> array(1) { 
["List"]=> ......
```

## What I am trying to do

something along those lines:

```
for($x=0; $x < $paraLgth; $x++) {
$val = $para[$x];
echo $val;
}
```

## My issue

I can see the Array is indeed an Array and the content is indeed a string but despite the research I have done on similar threads, I cannot understand for the life of me, why I cannot print the content of the Array.

Comment: you forgot to include the `List` index, `$para[$x]['List']` or just put `$para[] = $row['List'];` from the start on the while block

Comment: thanks @Ghost that fixed it